# css3 transform rotation of an image

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I would like to rotate an image 180 degrees when it is clicked. Then rotate that same image a further 180 degrees (completing the revolution) on subsequent click.

I have achieved the first part using:

```
.img_rotator_180 { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
.img_rotator_360 { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg); 
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
.img_rotator_transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: all 1s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+
}
```

And

```
$('div.' + this.id + ' img').addClass('img_rotator_180 img_rotator_transition');
```

Alternative version:

```
$('div.' + this.id + ' img').addClass('img_rotator_180 img_rotator_transition');
```

What happens with this is that the images initial rotation is not remembered meaning that the second rotation effectively redoes the 180 degree rotation.

Is there a way to establish the images current rotation before applying further transformation? Or perhaps a way to append rotation rather than replace it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxKJ6/8/)

HTML

```
<div>Click Me!</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('spinIn')) {
        $(this).addClass('spinOut').removeClass('spinIn');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('spinIn').removeClass('spinOut');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.spinIn {
    -webkit-animation: spinIn 0.6s 1 linear;
    animation: spinIn 0.6s 1 linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinIn {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spinIn {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}
.spinOut {
    -webkit-animation: spinOut 0.6s 1 linear;
    animation: spinOut 0.6s 1 linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinOut {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spinOut {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer ! But the OP asks to *complete* the revolution. spinOut should have the 100% transform at rotate(360deg)